# Python Error:'int' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, get, cloud, shapes, point

```
def get_model(point_cloud, is_training, bn_decay=None):
    """ Classification PointNet, input is BxNx3, output Bx40 """
    batch_size = point_cloud.get_shape()[0].value
    num_point = point_cloud.get_shape()[1].value
    end_points = {}**
    
    with tf.variable_scope('transform_net1') as sc:
        transform = input_transform_net(point_cloud, is_training, bn_decay, K=3)
    point_cloud_transformed = tf.matmul(point_cloud, transform)
    print(point_cloud_transformed)
    input_image = tf.expand_dims(point_cloud_transformed, -1)
    print(input_image)

    net = conv2d(input_image, 64, [1,3],
                         padding='VALID', stride=[1,1],
                         bn=True, is_training=is_training,
                         scope='conv1', bn_decay=bn_decay)
    net = conv2d(net, 64, [1,1],
                         padding='VALID', stride=[1,1],
                         bn=True, is_training=is_training,
                         scope='conv2', bn_decay=bn_decay)

    with tf.variable_scope('transform_net2') as sc:
        transform = feature_transform_net(net, is_training, bn_decay, K=64)
    end_points['transform'] = transform
    net_transformed = tf.matmul(tf.squeeze(net, axis=[2]), transform)
    net_transformed = tf.expand_dims(net_transformed, [2])

    net = conv2d(net_transformed, 64, [1,1],
                         padding='VALID', stride=[1,1],
                         bn=True, is_training=is_training,
                         scope='conv3', bn_decay=bn_decay)
    net = conv2d(net, 128, [1,1],
                         padding='VALID', stride=[1,1],
                         bn=True, is_training=is_training,
                         scope='conv4', bn_decay=bn_decay)
    net = conv2d(net, 1024, [1,1],
                         padding='VALID', stride=[1,1],
                         bn=True, is_training=is_training,
                         scope='conv5', bn_decay=bn_decay)
    # Symmetric function: max pooling
    net = max_pool2d(net, [num_point,1],
                             padding='VALID', scope='maxpool')
                             
    net = tf.reshape(net, [batch_size, -1])
    net = fully_connected(net, 512, bn=True, is_training=is_training,
                                  scope='fc1', bn_decay=bn_decay)
    net = dropout(net, keep_prob=0.7, is_training=is_training,
                          scope='dp1')
    net = fully_connected(net, 256, bn=True, is_training=is_training,
                                  scope='fc2', bn_decay=bn_decay)
    net = dropout(net, keep_prob=0.7, is_training=is_training,
                          scope='dp2')
    net = fully_connected(net, 40, activation_fn=None, scope='fc3')

    return net, end_points
```

Comment: Hi, I assume you are new to stack overflow, please provide some context to your question describing the problem and also remember that debugging is more difficult for us than you because we don't know your code and all the variables involved.
You provided a quite big piece of code without explanations, please shrink it to a smaller and simple example that shows your problem and give us some context

Answer (score 0):

my problem I am executing a code which allows to extract the saliency of a point cloud, it displays the following error:Error:'int' object has no attribute 'value' for the function :
def get_model(point_cloud, is_training, bn_decay=None):
""" Classification PointNet, input is BxNx3, output Bx40 """
batch_size = point_cloud.get_shape()[0].value
num_point = point_cloud.get_shape()[1].value
end_points = {}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).